# Laravel validation unique with where clause

Tags: laravel, validation, unique

I have table like this

```
+------+-----+
| name | age |
+------+-----+
|  joe | 20  |
+------+-----+
|  joe | 21  |
+------+-----+
|  ren | 22  |
+------+-----+
|  ren | 23  |
+------+-----+
```

I want to avoid duplicate in `age` where `name = joe`, I tried 
`unique:table_name,age,name,joe`

my insert is `age = 22 where name = joe`, but it gives me `age must be unique` because it also reads the `name ren`.

Please help

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate unique with combining two filed `name` and `age`.

For that check this https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator

Answer (score 0):

use this in your migration

```
$table->unique(['name' , 'age'])
```